# Understanding Android Memory Consumption

Tags: android, performance, memory

I am new to Android development and I would like to understand why my application is using this much memory when it starts. Right now, it starts off with 18MB of memory (using the memory monitor in Android Studio). I have added Firebase Analytics and Admob to it. I am worried that these are culprits of using this large amount of memory.

By doing some digging in, I found out that SharedPreferenceImpl and its children objects (FastXmlSerializer and ByteBuffer) were taking up 50% of the memory! I am pretty shocked. Next, I try to see which thread is generating these objects. I found out that the thread name is "thread-1-pool-1".

Here is the stacktrace responsible for creating this large amount of memory:

```
at java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(ByteBuffer.java:56) 
at com.android.internal.util.FastXmlSerializer.<init>(FastXmlSerializer.java:62)    
at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.writeMapXml(XmlUtils.java:188)    
at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.writeToFile(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:600)    
at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.-wrap2(SharedPreferencesImpl.java) 
at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl$2.run(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:515)  
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)  
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)  
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

I have a LoopThread that calls a method in a service. I am wondering if this could cause the large consumption of memory. My service class and loop thread contains no references to SharedPreferences though. So, I am very confuse why this happens. Any pointers would be appreciated.

The code may not be very clean and it is long. But here it is. The idea of this app is to bring up a screen saver when the power button is pressed.

This is the service class.

```
//SaverService.java
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Log.d("SaverService","Created saver service...");
    super.onCreate();

    loopThread = new LoopThread();
    loopThread.createHandler(this);
    loopThread.start();

    startSaverMethod();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, StartSaver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                                                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.pokeball)
                                                        .setContentTitle("Go-Saver's running")
                                                        .setContentText("Tap here to cancel")
                                                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    Notification notification = mBuilder.build();

    startForeground(1001, notification);
    return START_STICKY;
}

//SharedPreference should be a singleton
private void startSaverMethod() {
    //sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("GoSaverPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    try {
        //SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

        screenBrightness = Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS);
        previousScreenBrightness = screenBrightness;
        //editor.putInt("screenBrightness", screenBrightness);
       //editor.commit();

        screenBrightnessMode = Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE);
        previousScreenBrightnessMode = screenBrightnessMode;
        //editor.putInt("screenBrightnessMode",screenBrightnessMode);
        //editor.commit();

        screenOffTimeout = Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_OFF_TIMEOUT);
        previousScreenOffTimeout = screenOffTimeout;
        //editor.putInt("screenOffTimeout",screenOffTimeout);
        //editor.commit();
    } catch (Settings.SettingNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //Registerting receiver
    screenOffReceiver = new ScreenOffReceiver();
    screenOffReceiver.setSaverService(this);
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
    registerReceiver(screenOffReceiver, filter);


    Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_OFF_TIMEOUT, 3600000);

    pressedMillisec = getPressedMillisec();
}



@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.d("SaverService","Destroying saver service...");
    disableSaverSettings();

    //screenOffTimeout = sharedPreferences.getInt("screenOffTimeout", 30000);
    screenOffTimeout = previousScreenOffTimeout;
    Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_OFF_TIMEOUT, screenOffTimeout);
    unregisterReceiver(screenOffReceiver);

    removeScreenSaver();
    //sharedPreferences = null;
    windowManager = null;
    screenOffReceiver = null;

    Message killMessage = loopThread.handler.obtainMessage(LoopThread.KILL);
    loopThread.handler.sendMessage(killMessage);
    loopThread.handler.getLooper().quit();

    super.onDestroy();
    System.gc();
}

public boolean isScreenSaver() {
    if(screenSaver != null) {
        return screenSaver.isShown();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

private boolean isSaverBrightness() {
    try {
        int brightness = Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS);
        int brightnessMode = Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE);

        return brightness == 1 && brightnessMode == Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE_MANUAL;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("SaverService", "Cannot get brightness");
        return false;
    }
}

public void startScreenSaverAsync() {
    Message onMessage = loopThread.handler.obtainMessage(LoopThread.ON);
    loopThread.handler.sendMessage(onMessage);
}

public void startScreenSaver() {
    Log.d("SaverService","######################################");

    boolean isRightState = !isScreenSaver() && !isSaverBrightness();
    if (!isRightState) {
        Log.e("SaverService","Invalid state. Stopping service");
        stopSelf();
    }

    long currentMillisec = getPressedMillisec();
    if (currentMillisec - pressedMillisec < 2000) {
        Log.d("SaverService","Pressed too fast. Ignoring the second press.");
        return;
    }

    //Creating screenSaver
    windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    screenSaver = li.inflate(R.layout.screen_saver, null);

    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE |
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE |
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN |
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN |
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS |
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_INSET_DECOR |
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION |
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    long totalTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
    Log.d("SaverService","params Time: " + totalTime);

    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    enableSaverSettings();
    totalTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
    Log.d("SaverService","enableSaverSettings Time: " + totalTime);

    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    removeScreenSaver();
    totalTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
    Log.d("SaverService","removeScreenSaver Time: " + totalTime);

    Log.d("SaverService", "Adding Screen Saver");
    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    windowManager.addView(screenSaver, params);
    totalTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
    Log.d("SaverService","addView Time: " + totalTime);

    Log.d("SaverService", "Turning On Screen");
    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    turnOnScreen(this);
    totalTime = System.currentTimeMillis() -startTime;
    Log.d("SaverService","turnOnScreen Time: " + totalTime);

    pressedMillisec = getPressedMillisec();
    Log.d("SaverService", "Current time - " + pressedMillisec);
    Log.d("SaverService","######################################");
}

public void stopScreenSaverAsync() {
    Message offMessage = loopThread.handler.obtainMessage(LoopThread.OFF);
    loopThread.handler.sendMessage(offMessage);
}

public void stopScreenSaver() {
    Log.d("SaverService","######################################");
    long currentMillisec = getPressedMillisec();
    if (currentMillisec - pressedMillisec < 2000) {
        Log.d("SaverService","Pressed too fast. Ignoring the second press.");
        return;
    }

    disableSaverSettings();
    removeScreenSaver();
    turnOnScreen(this);

    pressedMillisec = getPressedMillisec();
    Log.d("SaverService", "Current time - " + pressedMillisec);
    Log.d("SaverService","######################################");
}

private long getPressedMillisec() {
    return Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
}

private void removeScreenSaver() {
    try {
        windowManager.removeViewImmediate(screenSaver);
        screenSaver = null;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.w("SaverService", "Could not remove screen saver...");
    }
}

private void enableSaverSettings() {
    Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE, Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE_MANUAL);
    Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, 1);
}

private void disableSaverSettings() {
    screenBrightness = previousScreenBrightness;
    screenBrightnessMode = previousScreenBrightnessMode;
    //screenBrightness = sharedPreferences.getInt("screenBrightness", 50);
    //screenBrightnessMode = sharedPreferences.getInt("screenBrightnessMode", Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE_AUTOMATIC);
    Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE, screenBrightnessMode);
    Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, screenBrightness);
}

private void turnOnScreen(Context context) {
    //Wait for screen is off
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    boolean isScreenOn = pm.isScreenOn();

    while (isScreenOn) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2);
            isScreenOn = pm.isScreenOn();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("Issue", "Could not sleep...");
        }
    }

    Intent intentNew = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), Transparent.class);
    intentNew.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | IntentCompat.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    context.startActivity(intentNew);
}
```

This is the class that listens for a Power button press:

```
public class ScreenOffReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
private SaverService saverService = null;
private static boolean anyThreadRunning = false;


void setSaverService(SaverService saverService){
    this.saverService = saverService;
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    runMethod2(context, intent);
}

private void runMethod2(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    Log.d("SaverService", action);

    if(anyThreadRunning) {
        Log.d("SaverService","Another thread is using ScreenOffReceiver. Skipping... ");
        return;
    }

    if(action.equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF) && !saverService.isScreenSaver()){
        anyThreadRunning = true;
        Log.d("SaverService","Turning on screen saver.");
        saverService.startScreenSaverAsync();
    }
    else if(action.equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF) && saverService.isScreenSaver()){
        anyThreadRunning = true;
        Log.d("SaverService","Turning off screen saver." );
        saverService.stopScreenSaverAsync();
    }

    anyThreadRunning = false;
}
```

}

This the loop thread class:

```
public class LoopThread extends Thread {
public Handler handler = null;
public static final int ON = ScreenOffHandler.ON;
public static final int OFF = ScreenOffHandler.OFF;
public static final int KILL = ScreenOffHandler.KILL;
private SaverService saverService;

public void run(){
    Looper.prepare();
    handler = new ScreenOffHandler(saverService);
    Looper.loop();
}

public void createHandler(SaverService saverService){
    this.saverService = saverService;
}

private static class ScreenOffHandler extends Handler {
    private SaverService saverService;
    public static final int ON = 1;
    public static final int OFF = 0;
    public static final int KILL = -100;

    public ScreenOffHandler(SaverService saverService) {
        this.saverService = saverService;
    }


    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        // ...Run in background

        int what = msg.what;
        switch (what){
            case ON:
                saverService.startScreenSaver();
                break;
            case OFF:
                saverService.stopScreenSaver();
                break;
            case KILL:
                saverService = null;
                break;

        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Edit to include the code that generates the memory.

Comment: @sub6resources I have added the code that is causing this issue.

Comment: @YaoHongKok  I am also facing this problem, did you find any solution to this crash